# Django: display only the items available in an admin form | OneToOneField

Tags: python, django

I have 4 class models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Buy(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}' 

class Sell(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.buyer}'
```

In the form admin page, the `item field` (Sell class) shows all the items available in the Buy model, regardless they've already been chosen before. As this items belongs to OneToOneField it doesn't make sense to display them because they can't be added anymore.

Example:

```
Buy
id category buy_price
6  ring     20
7  ring     30  
8  ring     40

Sell
item total_paid buyer
6    80         Ana
7    100        Kate
```

What the admin form is displaying:
[image]

What I was expecting is to be shown only the item 8, the one who has not been added before. In this way, how can I display only the items, in the admin form, that hasn't been chosen yet?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide your models with completely.

Comment: @binpy now I'm done!

Comment: You can modify your modelAdmin and add the method  formfield_for_foreignkey (here is the link to the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

Answer (score 1):

After some hours studying I think I figure out how to solve this issue:

```
class SellAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "item":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Buy.objects.filter(sell__buyer__isnull=True)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```